# Regex of negative and positive hexadecimal number

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression for hexadecimal number (negative or positive)?
i need for a code that can recognise if the number i entered is hexadecimal (it can be irrational number or negative number)

possible numbers it will accept:

```
123.23
23
12F12.A1
-12C1
-23.5
-AB.34
```

The decimal point is optional.

Comment: Here is one attempt you really could try  - search on Google: https://www.google.pl/search?q=hexadecimal+number+regex.

Comment: I searched on google an i tried to find out by myself, but i didn't find any regex that support decimal point and negative numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the following regex:

```
-?([\dA-Fa-f]+)(\.?[\dA-Fa-f]+)?
```

[Here your example in regex101!](https://regex101.com/r/fC2sS8/4)

Next time consider trying to find out the needed regex with regex101 first before asking. It is easier than it looks at first glance ;)

Comment: The number with only one digit are not accepted in your solution. (For exemple '1' or 'A') Because you have a + then an other + so 'at least one time' then 'at least one time'. You need two digit in that case. I don't think you can unpack the '.' from the digits following

Comment: I forgot about this case. Updated regex to cover also one digit numbers.

Comment: Edited again, so in case of match pre and post comma values can be retrieved from the capture groups.

Comment: The '.?' should be inside the second parentesis. Because now your regex accept 'A.' but the dot without any number after should not be accepted. I'll upvote once corrected.

Comment: Oops, thats right...Corrected

Comment: `123x23` is successfully matched by your expression. You forgot to escape the `.`.

Comment: Yes, plus, I'm sorry I made an error while correcting you, the "?" after the dot in second parenthese is not needed anymore. It will still work but don't change anything, therefore, you should remove it.

Comment: thank you ! i didn't knew about this site, i'll use it for my future searches.

Answer (score 0):

`-?[0-9A-F]+(\.[0-9A-F]+)?`

The explanation : 
`-?` May or may not start with a ' - '

`[0-9A-F]` Accept from 0 to 9 or from A to F (only capital letter)

`+`  Because you want this 1 or more time. (You can't have no number before the dot)

`(`   Start a group

`\.` A dot, must be escaped for interpretation.

`[0-9A-F]`  Same as before

`+` If you have a dot you MUST have something after it.

`)`  End the group

`?`  The group (\.[0-9A-F]+) is optionnal. (0 or 1 time)

Comment: Looks like escaping the dot isn't needed. I leave it in the post untill someone confirm.

Comment: What test cases did you try to conclude that "escaping the dot isn't needed"?

Comment: The wrong ones. It is needed.